# What would be an appropriate title for a position focused on system logging?

Tags: logging, syslog, analysis

I am interested in any training involved with system logging, log catching, network device logging, log extraction, log analysis, log presentation... and so forth.  I am looking to focus on all things involved with system monitoring and alerting, as well as historical review of various system metrics.

Does anybody work in such a position?  What is your title?  What would be a good title for such a position?

UPDATE
I am asking this in an attempt to figure out what sort of training I might want to pursue in a focus on what amounts in a vague sense to "system analysis"  I use Splunk to index all sorts of logs, and I am finding that it is somewhat tricky working with all the various systems in the environment... the best way of interrogating the information, than working over it to generate insight.

Comment: Why is this a Community Wiki??

Comment: Maybe some kind of forensic specialist in law enforcement?

Comment: I might be displaying ignorance of the purpose of Community Wiki, but I made it wiki because I thought it was a sort of a subjective, not exactly server admin sort of topic.

Comment: CWs are for building a base of knowledge, without asking a question or where the question is largely rhetorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most positions centered around reviewing audit trails and logs are security analysts or administrators of various types.  In IT, the responsibilities are security focused and it's usually entry to mid level positions.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's too many jobs around that solely focus on system logs. It's basically required of every sysadmin to keep track of his own logs; though if the organization is large enough they might have a person or two dedicated to logging functions. These people would more than likely come from sysadmin backgrounds and would not have simply started in the area.

Comment: Plenty of security jobs out there.

Comment: @Warner, I wouldn't think they'd hire people who only review logs though; I would think they'd be, well, Security Experts and a part of that job is Logs. I'm sure there are a few out there, but I can't imagine they'd ever hire someone without prior admin experience.

Comment: I'd call SNORT's review logs but in large corp, there's not much of a difference.  =)